# How my calculation can work with this format?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a text box at top which displays the total duration. Now what happens is the user selects a duration from a timepicker and this will be displayed in the textbox and then add it into a new row. 
Now the situation I have is that the format of the textbox is like this "00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs".

So for example if the total duration was 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs and if you select 00 Hrs 20 Mins 00 Secs from the timeicker (displayed in the textbox) and then add it into a new row, then 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs should minus 00 Hrs 20 Mins 00 Secs to make 00 Hrs 10 Mins 00 Secs.

The thing is that I know how to do the calculation but I do not how to match it with in the 00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs format. My calculation works for a normal number format but how can I get it working with this format?

```
    Below is my jquery code which does the calculation:

var duration = '<?php echo $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>'

        $("#qandatbl td.duration input").live("change", function(){
            calculateDuration();
        });

        function calculateDuration()
        {
           var totalduration = duration;  
    //duration is the variable which displays total duration e.g 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs
           $("#qandatbl td.duration input").each(function (i, elm){
                totalduration = totalduration - parseInt($(elm).val(), 10);
            });

            $("#total-duration").text(totalduration);
        }
```

Below is html code:

```
    <table id="questionDuration">
    <tr>
         <th colspan="2">
         Question Duration
         </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="questiondurationpicker" name="questionDuration" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    // timepicker textbox for duration
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Total Duration Remaining: <span id="total-duration"></span></td>
    this is where the total duration is displayed
    </tr>
    </table>


    <table id="qandatbl" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="duration">Question Duration</th>
    </tr>
    </table>

    // above is where the duration selected is stored in a new row
```

Comment: If you had a working fiddle for this it would be easier to find an answer...

Comment: I won't be able to provide a fiddle for this example, because the variable "duration", actually retrieves a php variable of the total duration entered in another page. I can show you a working sample of something very similar with ordinary numbers that works exactly the same. Only difference like I said is that this textbox has format 00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs while the one in the fiddle is just ordinary numbers. In  fiddle just enter in a number and click on "Add" to add it in new row and a calculation would occur. http://jsfiddle.net/uThKQ/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

EDIT:

---

Look at this fiddle.

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/15/</s>

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/16/  (faster version)

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/17/ (force two digits e.g 9 = 09)

HTML

```
current Time: <span id="currentTime">25 Hrs 24 Mins 45 Secs</span>
<hr>
subtract Time: <span id="minusThis">07 Hrs 15 Mins 21 Secs</span>
<hr>
new Time: <span id="newTime"></span>
<hr>

<button>subtract the time</button>
```

jQuery

```
var minusThis = $('#minusThis').text(),
    date = minusThis.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
    currentTime = $('#currentTime').text(),
    newDate = currentTime.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
    newsetH = parseInt(date[0], 10),
    newsetM = parseInt(date[1], 10),
    newsetS = parseInt(date[2], 10),
    hours = parseInt(newDate[0], 10),
    mins = parseInt(newDate[1], 10),
    secs = parseInt(newDate[2], 10);


function calculate() {
    newH = hours - newsetH;
    newM = mins - newsetM;
    newS = secs - newsetS;
    $('#newTime').text(newH + ' Hrs ' + newM + ' Mins ' + newS + ' Secs');
}

$('button').on('click', calculate);
```

Comment: @user1131869   does this help at all?

Comment: Hi, I was looking at both fiddles. I am just wondering though, the total duration is retrieved like tihs: var duration = '<?php echo $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>';. Now $_POST['durationChosen']; is stored like 00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs, so I am thinking that it cannot to be possible to split that into 3 sections? can you? I included this in first jquery code in question so you can see how it works in the code

Comment: maybe if you use the technique from @dreame4. You could use the array values and do the same calculation. then it should work.  I also added this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/7/

Comment: Well I was wondering how can I do this for example, total duration was 01 Hr 30 Mins 00 Secs and user selects 00 Hrs 59 Mins 00 Secs and adds it to new row, then the new total duration is 00 Hrs, 31 Mins 00 Secs?

Comment: Yeah Dream4 is a good example. I was wondering though, if I include this in my code var durationvalue = duration.match(/(\d\d)/ig); , does it mean var totalduration = duration;  or var totalduration = durationvalue; in my code?

Comment: look at this.. you can manually enter the time to subtract  http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/9/

Comment: Hey that last fiddle was a great fiddle to show how the calculation works. I want to know if you can show me the way you would do it if you included Dream4's code in it where except splitting it into 3 timeforms, it is all in one time form. I have upvote your answer by the way because of the effort you are putting in to helping me solve this problem. I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm really not good with arrays ;)... Otherwise I would have already included it. But sure I can give it a try. This is very interesting to me. A cleaner version of my last fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/URLR5/12/  .. I'll try to combine @dreame4 's answer and mine...

Comment: Haha, I am not very good with arrays as well. Arrays and Loops I really hate :), thats why I asked if you know how to do it

Comment: I just updated my answer. It is a combination of @dreame4 and my original answer

Comment: That looks like it is working perfectly, Thank you very much for your time and effort you put in solving this problem for me :). Best Answer

Comment: @user1131869  I added another example (fiddle # 17)  that forces a two digit output (9 = 09)

Answer (score 0):

Saying that textbox has a format "00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs" you mean a text input with a value for example "00 Hrs 10 Mins 00 Secs"?

If so, you just need to get these numbers from string. You can achieve this by a simple regular expression. For example:

```
var value = "10 Hrs 20 Mins 00 Secs";
var date = value.match(/(\d\d)/ig); // now date is an array. In this case ["10", "20", "00"]
```

Hope it helps.

BTW. Attaching `change` event can be rewritten this way:

```
$("#qandatbl td.duration input").live("change", calculateDuration);
```

Much cleaner and unnecessary function isn't created.

Comment: How can I include the var date in my calculation so that it calculates it